# How do I utilize actions and components to handle client side errors with Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, error-handling

From what I've seen, most people use an external service that 'just works' and then they throw in some code in an initializer to report the errors.

In my initializer, so far I have:

```
Ember.onerror = function(error) {
  displayError(error);
};
```

and `displayError` shows an error notification (similar to the Atom editor's error notifications)

But as I'm trying to add functionality to my displayError function (appending multiple errors, close one / all, showing stacktrace, eventually posting issues to github, etc), I've been finding that it's just VERY cumbersome to go back to vanilla javascript, and am wondering if there is a way to utilize ember to report errors that happen in my app.

Does anyone either:
- Know of an addon that does all this for me (I'm not interested in using a bug reporting service other than github)
- Know of a way to have `Ember.onerror` trigger an action in the application controller so I can have use components to render the errors, and have much easier development implementing what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always try and use something like [Ember.Instrumentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Instrumentation.html).

This will allow you fire off an event from inside the Ember.onerror callback that you can subscribe to anywhere else in your app. So let's say you create a component that lives at the root of your application. You can then subscribe that component to the error event and trigger when to display the error. `Ember.instrument()` also allows you to pass a payload which can be the error object itself.

In the root of your app you can have something like this:

```
Ember.onerror = function(error) {
  Ember.Instrumentation.instrument("app.error", error);
};
```

Then in you're component you can subscribe to events in the `init` function like this:

```
 init: function() {
   Ember.Instrumentation.subscribe("app.error", {
     before: function(name, timestamp, payload) {
       // do logic here with error
     },
     after: function() {
       // optional cleanup work here
     }
   }
 }
```